# DPM Setup: The evaluation copy of DPM has expired. (ID: 3751)

Tags: scdpm

When I evaluated System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM/SCDPM) TP5 I stumbled across this problem: Because TP4 was previously installed on this server, and expired, I couldn't start the TP5 setup:

[image: Screenshot of DPM setup error 3751]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete this registry key:

```
HKCR\Licenses\830D982D-9ADC-4479-85CE-6474F7D00BB1
```